# Load swf file on click of (javascript)navigation label

Tags: javascript, flash

I am trying to make a  (heavy)swf file slideshow. for that i have created navigation labels at the bottom of the html page using javascript.And my my 'aim' is when i 'll click on any navigation label,particular swf file will be loaded. Here i'm getting problem is , when i open that html file all swf files are loaded at the same time. so when i click on nxt label part of swf only displays.

so what is the soln to this?

is there any way that when i'll click on navigation label only that time particular swf file will played and when i'll go to nxt label, previous label shoud have to unload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of pre-loading, you should load the SWF files dynamically, changing the `src` attribute of the element in the moment it is displayed.